# Math in Texture Nodes

Tags: texturing, node-editor, mathematics

I’m having trouble figuring out how a math node influences a texture node. Say you have the Musgrave Texture node and put the output into an add node. Does the node add all the values within the texture node such as Scale, Detail, Dimension, etc?

Answer (score 0):

The output of a Musgrave texture is, for each pixel of the texture, a value between 0 (black) and 1 (white). If you plug that into a Add node, you add that value with the second value of the Add node :
[image]